# Proving uniqueness of solution to an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why when we solve equations we don't prove that there are no other solutions to it ?

For an example, I saw a solution to the equation 8^x=x^6 which concluded that x=4, but the solver never proved that there are no other solutions to the equation (like x=2...).

Shouldn't we always address additional possible solutions in all cases, even if it's a simple case, like x-1=0 ?

Comment: This is not true. We determine all solutions. For example, $2x=4$ has a unique solution, but $2x+3y=4$ has infinitely many real solutions. We prove that all solutions are given by $y=(4-2x)/3$, and that there are no other solutions to it.

Comment: Your question seems by no means trivial; at high school level maths, at least. But please, put some example. motivations, etc

Comment: It depends on the way that the equation is solved, @DietrichBurde

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you edited your post to include an example of what you mean.  Generally speaking, we want *all* the solutions, not just some.  Of course, in some problems, real world considerations let us reject some solutions as unphysical.

Comment: Solving third or higher degree equations we often 'solve' them trying integer or rational solutions, using the rational root theorem, but they can have more irrational solutions. And the question hits at the heart of logical deduction.

Comment: Post edit:  There's no reason I can see for skipping the other real solutions to that eqution (assuming you were only looking for real solutions).  There's even a negative solution, though that one isn't an integer.

Comment: @lulu I'm new to math so excuse my silly question...but in some sense I just can't understand why everywhere I look for guidance on how to solve equations (websites, books,...) they all jump straight to finding x but never mention if it's the only x possible...

Comment: Your question is fine.  If someone is discarding solutions, for whatever reason, they should explain why. For instance, in your example, perhaps we knew that the desired solution was an integer between $-1$ and $3$.  In that case, we could easily check that $x=2$ was the only relevant solution.  But all this should be stated, not just handled silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first degree equations the solution must be unique.

The reason is that every 'step' is a *deduction*.

That is, if you assume that $x-1=0$, then the consequence is that $x=1$. Because if $A=B$ then $A+1=B+1$. In this case, $(x-1)+1=0+1$, that is, $x=1$.

To summarize: the method to solve first-degree equations is in such way that we get the solutions as *consequences* of the equation, so there can't be more solutions.

If we got the solutions just trying there *could be* more solutions. A quadratic equation may illustrate this point.

Take for example $x^2+x+1=3$. It is relatively easy getting the solution $x=1$. We try, check and it works. But there can be, and there is, one more solution. Namely $x=-2$. But there can't be more solutions because the well-known formula is a *deduction* from the equation, not just a pick-and-try.

The equation $8^x=x^6$ is interesting. There is no standard way to solve equations if the unknown is both 'inside' and 'outside' the exponent.

And indeed $x=2$ and $x=4$ are solutions. Are there more? Well, let's see. I assume that you are about *real* solutions. (I mean real numbers).

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{8^x}{x^6}$ for $x\neq 0$ has, say, a 'child' (must of 'useful' funtions have, too). It is called, derivative. It is a function that says to us when $f$ is increasing or decreasing. It is called the derivative and it is so related to $f$ that we mathematicians name it $f'$ (That is, the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x)$, for example).

The derivative of $\dfrac{8^x}{x^6}$ is $(x\ln 8-6)\dfrac{8^x}{x^7}$. If the derivative is positive, the function increases, and if the derivative is negative, the function decreases.

The factor $8^x/x^7$ has the same sign as $x$, and the factor $x\ln 8-6$ is positive if $x>\log_8 e^6\approx 2.885$ and negative otherwise. Call this number $\alpha$.

So, if $0<x<\alpha$ the solution $x=2$ is unique, because if $x$ is bigger, then $8^x/x^6$ is lesser than $1$, and if $x$ is smaller, then $8^x/x^6$ is greater than $1$. For $x>\alpha$, the solution $x=4$ is also unique, as you can show using a similar reasoning.

There is also a negative solution of $8^x=x^6$, but it is probably so a strange number that it cannot be written with an elementary formula. An approximation is $-0.767$.

Comment: Thanks, it is clearer now.

Comment: so is it safe to say that when "non standard" (as you mentioned) equation is presented, one should prove how many solutions exist before trying to find them? Because I never encountered people that do that, they just went on solving for x (which clearly not a good strategy with "non standard" equations).